# Create multiple agents in the same container in JADE

Tags: java, agents-jade, multi-agent

Is it possible to create multiples agents in the same container (not Main-Container) in Java Agent Development Framework (JADE)? I tried using -agents parameter but it didn't work. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

From the [tutorials](http://jade.tilab.com/doc/tutorials/JADEAdmin/startJade.html). To create an agent using command the command line use:

```
java -cp lib\jade.jar;classes jade.Boot -gui -agents ping1:examples.PingAgent.PingAgent
```

java jade.Boot  -agents "a:agents.AgentClass;b:agents.AgentClass"

Note that the classpath includes JADE classes (lib\jade.jar) and the previously compiled classes of the examples (classes). Note also that the value of the -agents option takes the form:

```
 <agent-local-name>:<fully-qualified-agent-class>
```

Using JADE terminology, this is called an "Agent Specifier". More than one agent can be started by just typing several agent specifiers separated by a semicolon (';') as in the example below:

```
 java -cp lib\jade.jar;classes jade.Boot -gui -agents ping1:examples.PingAgent.PingAgent;ping2:examples.PingAgent.PingAgent
```